# Jquery UI, Icons on radio buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, radio-button

With jQuery UI you can set icons from the framework on button, i want to do the exact same thing on the radio buttons.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio

Framework icons (bottom of the page) :
http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Comment: on the link there is source code. what do you ask?

Comment: in jQuery UI you can set icons from the framework i want the same thing on the radio button this time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can do it, just set the icons like this:

```
$( "#radio1" ).button( "option", "icons", {primary:'ui-icon-gear',secondary:'ui-icon-triangle-1-s'} );
```

With each respective id for each radio element, and using primary and/or secondary as you need, as you can see on this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/Gr4h3/)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, need 5 more minutes to accept your answer ;)